# How to write own AdBlock-like plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, adblock

I'm interested in the simple example of how the content is blocked. Documentation at "https://adblockplus.org/en/filters" very scanty, and how to use "https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt" also don't have desirible descriptions. For example, how to use a filter rule. For example how to create a select query from rule "&ad_box_".

```
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="&ad_box_"]'); // maybe like that?
```

If there is a minimalist example of JavaScript code using these rules I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways on how you can block ads:

1. Block a request by matching its URL
2. Hide an element on a page using CSS selectors

The filter you're referring to (i.e. `&ad_box_`) belongs to the former which means that any URL that contains `&ad_box_` should get blocked. Hiding filters, on the other hand, can be identified by `##` followed by a CSS selector (e.g. `##body div.foo`).

Note that Adblock Plus is open source so you can find its entire source code [on GitHub](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockplus).